# confused on usage/difference of SSO/OAUTH/SOCIAL LOGIN

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social

I have an app idea and need to implement authentication. Because of the nature of my app, I only want linkedin users to be able to access my app.

After reading a bit about spring oauth / spring social / etc, it seems its definitely possible to use something like Linkedin to access MY app. I want a user to see linkedins login button on the first view of my app, create my own version of this user in my app, and then allow the user to use my app.

After my findings I have found the generic flow

`*user authenticates via social login button
*client app redirects user to service provider to receive a token
*client uses token and makes another request to service provider to receive auth token
*now my client app can make calls to service provider with auth token of user(this is the part where I am a bit confused)
*I want to use this token to validate calls against MY api NOT linkedins(is this wrong)`

I don't really care to make calls to Linkedin on behalf of the user(except to pull user information). I ONLY want linkedin auth so that I know that users who use my auth are valid linkedin users. I thought something similar to Tinder where you MUST have a facebook account, I want to copy that design but couldn't find any hints from google. It seems the examples I find online all use the social login to ultimately use the service providers API.

I also read some stuff about SSO which sounds like what I want, but I definitely plan to add at least 1 more social login down the road. My clients will use a browser or mobile app.

I guess the main question here is once I authenticate a user using social login, am I supposed to use his existing connection to make calls to my API or create a new connection somehow. My goal is when a user does a social login, he now can access MY app, I want to reuse their existing connection without authenticating them into mine(only store their info). I want to follow best practices.